# Azure service bus client updating scheduled messages (changing their enqueue schedule time)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azureservicebus

I need to update enqueue times of already scheduled messages in a service bus queue. I tried different approaches, but I wasn't successful at all. I tried peeking messages, then receiving messages that I'm looking for or at least completing that message, but messages can not be completed when we peek at them. Is there maybe any function to get a message by its sequence number or do you have any other approach or solution that could solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update a scheduled message but what you can do is cancel the schedule and *re-schedule* the same message. This is done with the help of its **sequence number**.

Below is an example of cancelling a scheduled message:

```cs
    var queueName = "<queue>";
    var connectionString = "<connection-string>";

    var client = new ServiceBusClient(connectionString);
    var sender = client.CreateSender(queueName);

    //  Scheduling a new message
    var sequenceNumber = await sender.ScheduleMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(), new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10)));

    // Cancelling the above scheduled message
    await sender.CancelScheduledMessageAsync(sequenceNumber);
```

Now that you cancelled the scheduled message, you can schedule it again with same message details. In your case, you have to peek the message first to get your exact message details like sequence number, message body, etc.

Comment: can you help me with this for nodejs setup

Comment: @hardikmandankaa I haven't worked with nodejs but it should be possible. Here's a link to read about sending scheduled messages in javascript - https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples/v7/javascript/scheduledMessages.js You can check at line 64.

Comment: @hardikmandankaa You can cancel a scheduled message using this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/service-bus/servicebussender?view=azure-node-latest#@azure-service-bus-servicebussender-cancelscheduledmessages